# Sorting item with checkbox checked at the top of the list in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Im comparing two object arrays and displaying them with those that have the same object checkbox checked. I now want to sort the list the with checkbox check to be first as a default state.
I also want to sort by clicking the header to sort by ascending order .

```
 <div>header</div>
    <div class="search" ng-repeat="items in products ">
        <label >{{item.name}}</label>

   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" 
                          ng-click="checked(item,productlist)"
                          ng-checked=" checked(item,productlist)"> 
    </div>
```

I  tried using `orderBy:[‘-checked’,’item’]: true` to sort the checked ones on top but its not working. Any ideas

Comment: You've forced the second argument to `orderBy` to `true`, which will always sort the items in reverse order. Also, specifying `'item'` as a secondary ordering field might not work as you'd expect because it'd be comparing by object reference. http://plnkr.co/edit/quxAI4?p=preview

Comment: Thanks this works fine when checkbox are tick after page load but not when checkbox are pre-check before page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems here...

1. You have `ng-repeat="items in products"`, but then you refer to `item` instead of `items` within this scope.
2. You have this `checked()` method that you're passing to `ng-click` and `ng-checked`. What exactly is this doing? You should never be using `ng-checked` in conjunction with `ng-model` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked
3. By passing `'-checked'` to `orderBy`, items will be ordered by their `checked` value in reverse, i.e. they will be ordered `false` first, `true` last. Then you're passing `true` as the `reverse` parameter to `orderBy`, so the list will be reversed again. You're reversing the ordering twice unnecessarily - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

This might work better...

```
<div>header</div>
<div class="search" ng-repeat="item in products | orderBy: 'checked'">
    <label>{{item.name}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
</div>
```